# Parse deploy of cloud code failing with message "Update failed with internal error"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've been running Parse cloud code for a few months using CLI version 1.4.1 with no problems. I just updated using the CLI to the latest version, 1.4.2, but now when I deploy I get this output:

```
Uploading source files
Finished uploading files
Update failed with internal error
```

I've checked for the one problem I see documented elsewhere, which is erroneous quotes around some parse classes like Parse.User and Parse.Installation. It doesn't look like these are my problem.

Is there any way to find out more about the error, besides trial and error with my several thousand lines of code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon upload attempt, Parse is parsing your code (pun intended :-) checking for errors, and deployment fails if any errors found.

One possibility is to check **Logs** (in your Dashboard under Core/Logs), also the Error submenu of Logs.

Another is to run the command  [`parse develop your_app`](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#clt) and see all the errors in your terminal.

For a large code, you probably want to write some unit tests if you aren't doing this already.