# How to download older versions of Parse CLI?

Tags: parse-platform, command-line-interface, parse-cloud-code

I'm having a compatibility issue with the current Parse CLI (v1.4.2) and I'm trying to find a copy of an older version such as 1.4.1.

I know, from inspecting the install script that the initial curl command accesses, that the current version is located at https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/parse .

Is there any location for older versions of the CLI? Google searching for site:parse.com/downloads/cloud_code doesn't turn anything up.

Comment: As far as I know Parse does not offer older version for previous versions of tools/SDKs. If you feel this issue is a bug you should file a bug report here https://parse.com/help. This will help Parse get better and help other developers. What issue are you seeing with 1.4.2?

Comment: I wrote up my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031309/parse-deploy-of-cloud-code-failing-with-message-update-failed-with-internal-err

Comment: Question title is 'Parse deploy of cloud code failing with message "Update failed with internal error"'